# What exactly is the JIT compiler inside a JVM?

Tags: java, jvm

I'm trying to understand how Java source code is executed and I'm confused as to what the JIT-compiler inside the JVM actually is. To start off let me tell you how I understand the process of going from Java source code to executing machine code on a computer. Perhaps, I'm misunderstanding something in the process that is causing the confusion.

The steps:

1. The source code is compiled into bytecode (.class files)
2. The class files are loaded into the JVM (which is in RAM)
3. the bytecode is verified and then processed by the JIT compiler
4. the output of the JIT compiler is machine code ready for execution

Now, according to the [Wikipedia article on JVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine), and more specifically the "Bytecode interpreter and just-in-time compiler" section, in order to execute Java bytecode you need an **interpreter** (but we have a JIT **compiler**).

Now here's the bit that is confusing to me. I've broken it down into quotes:

**"When Java bytecode is executed by an interpreter, the execution will always be slower than the execution of the same program compiled into native machine language."**

1. Since the computer can only execute machine code, and an interpreter is slower at translating the bytecode to machine code than a compiler is, why does the JVM use an interpreter and not a compiler?
2. Why do we not have another intermediate executable file generated by the JIT compiler for the CPU so it can quickly execute the instructions?

**"A JIT compiler may translate Java bytecode into native machine language while executing the program. The translated parts of the program can then be executed much more quickly than they could be interpreted. This technique gets applied to those parts of a program frequently executed."**

Is the JIT compiler really an interpreter that has the ability to compile frequently executed code? Are the terms compiler and interpreter wrongfully used interchangeably?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The term 'JIT Compller' is really obsolete. It refers to a JVM plugin architecture prior to 1.3 that compiled all bytecode prior to execution. It was found that 'JIT compilers spray code everywhere', which led to what we have now, which is called 'HotSpot', which *selectively* compiles bytecode based on its execution history. The current tendency, as per your Wikipedia citation, is to use 'JIT' to refer to both, but really this is just confusing, as well as being historically inaccurate.

Comment: @EJP Thanks for your reply. When you say it refers to both, do you mean both, compiler and interpreter? So if I understand correctly, at first the translator inside the JVM was a compiler but due to security problems was replaced. This means that prior to 1.3, the entire translation process from source code to machine code had 2 separate compilation steps. One from the source code to bytecode and the other from bytecode to machine code. Currently the translator is more like an interpreter that executes code line by line and occasionally acts as a compiler for frequently used code. Correct?

Comment: Another thing I was wondering about is how exactly the machine code reaches the CPU. I assume when the code processed line by line, then interpreter just passes on that machine code. What is not as obvious is how does the CPU get the machine code when you have an intermediate file that contains the machine code. Does the compiler feed the CPU instructions from the file?

Comment: I mean that the  Wikipedia article you cited refers to both JIT compilers and the HotSpot JVM as the same thing, which they aren't by a country mile. I tried to edit it once but the thought police objected. The situation in the late 1990s was that JIT DLLs were provided by third parties, Symantec for example, and were *enabled* via a command line option to the JVM, which incidentally answers another of your questions above, whereas HotSpot is built into the JVM and is *disabled* via a command line option. There is no intermediate file which contains machine code under either JITs or HotSpot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Since the computer can only execute machine code, and an interpreter is slower at translating the bytecode to machine code than a compiler is, why does the JVM use an interpreter and not a compiler?

Because compiling to machine code also takes time, especially when it has to analyze the code to optimize it, so interpreting is fast enough to execute most of the time, and actually faster than compile+run if only run once/occationally.

Also, an interpreter doesn't "translating the bytecode to machine code". It evaluates the bytecode and performs the operations requested by the bytecode. The interpreter itself is machine code, but it doesn't translate bytecode, it interprets/evaluates the bytecode.

> Why do we not have another intermediate executable file generated by the JIT compiler for the CPU so it can quickly execute the instructions?

That would violate the Write Once, Run Anywhere paradigm of Java.

> Is the JIT compiler really an interpreter that has the ability to compile frequently executed code?

No, the JIT compiler (or more accurately, the HotSpot compiler, as [mentioned by EJP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41497761/what-exactly-is-the-jit-compiler-inside-a-jvm#comment70201796_41497761)) is a compiler executed by the JVM as needed.

> Are the terms compiler and interpreter wrongfully used interchangeably?

Correct. They cannot be used interchangeably, since they don't do the same thing. The interpreter *executes* bytecode. The JIT/HotSpot compiler converts bytecode to machine code, but doesn't run it.

Comment: Hmm, Ok! Based on your answer and that of CoronA, it appears as though every time some source code is processed and executed, an interpreter is involved at some stage. Simply put, interpretation is required but compilation is not. I guess in compiled languages, the interpretation step is explicit(as in the case with Java) and implicit in interpreted languages.

Comment: Also, why do you say that having a second intermediate file of compiled code would violate the "Write Once, Run Anywhere" paradigm? In fact I think that's how Java works with bytecode compilation. As you said, the JIT compiler converts the bytecode to machine code which is then executed by the interpreter hence there is another intermediate step. Since the Java interpreter is machine specific, and the Java bytecode is not, then any Java interpreter can interpret the bytecode. This means you can write the program once and run it anywhere, does it not? Maybe I didn't word my question 2 correctly

Comment: @ribarcheto94 Ehh.. No... 1) Interpretation is not required. Not even for bytecode. JVM could choose to compile everything to machine code, in which case no interpretation would be done. 2) Languages that compile to machine code (e.g. C, C++) are not in any way interpreted. 3) Perhaps you didn't word it correct, because you said "Why do *we* not have another intermediate executable file", and *we* don't compile to machine code, because *we* want our output to run anywhere. What the JVM does is entirely up to *it*, and *we* don't care, as long as *it* does its job well.

Comment: LOL! If interpretation is not required why does the Wikipedia article on JVM say this: "For each hardware architecture a different Java bytecode interpreter is needed. When a computer has a Java bytecode interpreter, it can run any Java bytecode program, and the same program can be run on any computer that has such an interpreter." Based on your comment above, it appears as though the interpreter is just a wrapper on machine code instructions, correct? If compiled languages do not require interpretation how does the compiled code get executed?

Comment: @ribarcheto94 Because they *chose* not to compile everything to machine code, so an interpreter is needed to run the non-compiled code. If a JVM implementation *chooses* to compile everything to machine code, then *that* implementation will not need an interpreter. It is entirely up to the implementation. Having an interpreter is not mandatory, however I don't think there *are* any implementations that work that way. That doesn't mean there couldn't be. --- *End long repeat of what I said in #1.*

Comment: @ribarcheto94 You still don't seem to get what an interpreter is/does. It also doesn't matter is the code is a "compiled language" or not. If the code is compiled to machine code, then no interpreter is needed, since the CPU can run the machine code directly. If the code is not compiled, or if it is compiled to some intermediate format (e.g. bytecode), then an interpreter is needed to run the code. *Unless* the intermediate code is further compiled to machine code, in which case the interpreter is again not needed to run the code. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_(computing)

Comment: @ribarcheto94 The CPU runs the machine code. That is what a CPU does.

Comment: What does it mean for the interpreter to "run" code? Eventually everything must turn into machine code, right? If yes, then from what you said in your last comment, the interpreter appears to be doing an explicit step to reach machine code from some other code form and it doesn';t actually "execute" code as you mentioned in your first reply.

Comment: If the CPU is the only thing that runs machine code, then the interpreter definitely doesn't run machine code.

Comment: Sorry, if you refuse to actually read up on what an interpreter does, that's your decision, and you'll never learn. I gave you a link. Read it. You can also search the web. I'm done explaining.

Comment: I read the wiki on interpreter long before I posted the question. What I don't see is why the interpreter is defined as something that "executes code" when it actually DOES NOT. The CPU is what does the execution and the interpreter, like the compiler, only converts other code to machine code. They are both translators that work differently and have there advantages and shortfalls, but none of them actually execute code. This terminology is really stupid. I bet it's so easy but the terms are used incorrectly and cause massive confusion.

Comment: *Please grasp this:* An interpreter **DOES NOT** convert anything to machine code. It **interprets/evaluates** the requested instructions (e.g. bytecode) and performs/runs/executes the requested action.

Comment: I'm sorry, but what you are saying is contradictory.A CPU only understands machine code and thus in order to run something on the machine you need to transform it to machine code. How on Earth do we transform to this machine code when we use an interpreter????? I'm 100% sure the interpreter does not execute instructions because it's not a CPU. I may be novice but I'm not stupid.
 
According to your logic, an interpreter is an alternative to a CPU

Comment: *"I may be novice but I'm not stupid"* Really? Could have fooled me, since I've told you, repeatedly, I've given you a link to Wikipedia, and you still dont get what an interpreter is. Let's try *another* [link](http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/I/interpreter.html) (webopedia): *interpreter: A program that executes instructions written in a high-level language. There are two ways to run programs written in a high-level language. The most common is to compile the program; **the other method is to pass the program through an interpreter**.*

Comment: *An interpreter translates high-level instructions into an intermediate form, **which it then executes**. In contrast, a compiler translates high-level instructions directly into machine language. Compiled programs generally run faster than interpreted programs. **The advantage of an interpreter, however, is that it does not need to go through the compilation stage during which machine instructions are generated**.*

Comment: Here is a Super Duper Oversimplified Expression Interpreter: [IDEONE](https://ideone.com/FRdlUf). It can only understand expressions with the `+` operator, but it can parse an expression and **execute it**, aka evaluate it, aka interpret it, i.e. sum the numbers, **without** compiling anything to machine code. **That** is an interpreter: It interprets/evaluates/executes a set of instructions, without compiling to machine code. In this case, the instructions are a simple math expression.

Comment: Ok, perhaps you don't know this yourself but you still have not answered my question as to how the interpreter actually executes the instructions. An interpreter is a piece of software and all software depends on underlying hardware so I don't understand how a piece of software can work without the use of underlying hardware. In other words how does the interpreter do the job of the CPU?

Comment: Did you *bother* to look at the code I linked? I just wrote an teeny-tiny interpreter for you to showcase what an interpreter is. **I gave you an example**. How is this not answering how it does it? --- Oh well, *troll*, you got me good. Enjoy your win. Goodbye.

Answer (score 2):

> Since the computer can only execute machine code, and an interpreter
>   is slower at translating the bytecode to machine code than a compiler
>   is, why does the JVM use an interpreter and not a compiler?

Optimized Compiling is a very long lasting process. And this expense is only justified if the program runs a longer time.

Optimizations at the wrong places are unnecessary. A piece of code that is traversed only once will consume more compile time than interpretation time, so interpretation is ok.

Both subjects are better handled by a compiler that jumps in if certain sections of the code are processed frequently.

> Why do we not have another intermediate executable file generated by
>   the JIT compiler for the CPU so it can quickly execute the
>   instructions?

This "file" (the compiled fragments) does exist in memory. It is not serialized as file because:

- such a file would be heavily dependent on the operating system and the hardware
- there are certain code optimizations that can only be applied at runtime, e.g. the JIT-compiler can optimize virtual calls (replacing a dynmamic dispatch by a jump or even inlined code)

> Is the JIT compiler really an interpreter that has the ability to compile > frequently executed code? Are the terms compiler and interpreter
>   wrongfully used interchangeably?

While the JVM Hotspot compiler compiles frequently executed code, other JIT compilers may decide to compile depending on other heuristics. The terms "JIT compiler" and "interpreter" are not clearly distinguishable. Most interpreters optimize (compile just in time) and almost every JIT compiler interpretes.

Comment: 'Long lasting' is a poor description. It isn't long-lasting relative to the JVM running the application.

Comment: This was a general statement about optimized ahead-of-time compiling. the whole section should explain the benefits of just-in-time compiling above ahead-of-time compiling. So if we agree on the facts I can edit the post to be more succinct.